# I need to build an indexed array using a for loop from 1-117. Neither of my options are working

Tags: php, pdo

My Order_Items table has 117 items in it. So I need to build a for loop to collect and echo these items onto the screen, then after the user updates some of the items, I need to update the Order_Items table on the database.

I think I need to build an indexed array using a for loop from 1-117. Neither of my options are working, but I think this is close to what I need to do.

OPTION 1:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 117; $i++) {
    $item_qty[$i] = "SELECT Order_Items.qty 
                     FROM   Orders, Order_Items 
                     WHERE  Orders.id = Order_Items.order_id";
    }
```

OPTION 2:

```
$sql = "SELECT  Order_Items.qty 
        FROM    Orders, Order_Items 
        WHERE   Orders.id = Order_Items.order_id";

foreach ($database->query($sql) as $results)
 {
    echo $results["qty"];
 }
```

The Order_Items table layout is below for reference:

```
CREATE TABLE Order_Items (
  orders_id     INT(5) NOT NULL,
  line_item_id  INT(5) NOT NULL,
  part_id       INT(3),
  qty           INT(7),
  stockroom_id  INT(3),
  CONSTRAINT items_key  PRIMARY KEY (orders_id,line_item_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (orders_id)   REFERENCES Orders(id),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a loop and print the "qty" value,as you have tried in option 2, try this by way of example or reference.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
/*check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
}
/*Select queries return a resultset */
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT  order_item.qty from  Orders o inner join order_items order_item  on order_item.orders_id=o.id")) {
   echo "Returned rows". mysqli_num_rows($result)."<br>";
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo $row['qty'] . "<br>";
   }
   /*free result set */
   mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Table: order_items

```
CREATE TABLE `order_items` (
  `orders_id` INT(5) NOT NULL,
  `line_item_id` INT(5) NOT NULL,
  `part_id` INT(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `qty` INT(7) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `stockroom_id` INT(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Table orders:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `order` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL
 )
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

You will get output something like that:

```
Returned rows3
11
13
10
```

Comment: Thank you, @rescobar. That worked. Now I can continue to incorporate that into the main body of code.

Comment: @TimSideris ,happy to help you, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: another question, please. I have been using PDO for my queries, and although your mysqli_query works, I am struggling to convert it to the PDO format. I use require '../database.php'; to access the database. Then I have been doing my queries as if ($valid) {
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM ....)